# Download a particular version of a package with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, ruby

I wish to download a particular version of a package. The package in question is `ruby1.9.3` which has a Ubuntu native version and a Brightbox PPA version. I have the PPA version installed and that works great. From `apt-cache showpkg ruby1.9.3`:

```
Package: ruby1.9.3
Versions: 
1:1.9.3.392-1bbox1~quantal1 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: aa611a7522ee6c493d69294af0dd1d4b
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: aa611a7522ee6c493d69294af0dd1d4b

1.9.3.194-8.1ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: aa611a7522ee6c493d69294af0dd1d4b
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: aa611a7522ee6c493d69294af0dd1d4b
```

Downloading the Ubuntu native package is no problem: `apt-get source ruby1.9.3=1.9.3.194-8.1ubuntu1` but downloading the other with:

```
$ apt-get source ruby1.9.3=1:1.9.3.392-1bbox1~quantal1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'ruby1.9.1' as source package instead of 'ruby1.9.3'
E: Ignore unavailable version '1:1.9.3.392-1bbox1~quantal1' of package 'ruby1.9.3'
E: Unable to find a source package for ruby1.9.1
```

does not work.

I'm running 13.04 which I upgraded from 12.10. The PPA is defined as:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental/ubuntu quantal main
```

I'd like to do this because I want to create a Ruby 2.0 package as Brightbox is lagging in their releases and I'd like to figure out how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the package from a PPA. When doing an upgrade to the new version of Ubuntu, PPAs are automatically disabled. So, the `deb-src` line is no longer in use, and thus `apt-get` cannot find the source package. You will need to re-enable the PPA, and then run `apt-get update` to be able to pull that specific source.

Comment: I, indeed, noticed the original entry in `sources.list.d` was disabled and a new one appeared with a `.distUpgrade` suffix. I was under the impression this would still work. However I've readded the PPA and ran `apt-get update` the raring version now also shows but the error persists.

Comment: The *exact* same error message? If you've swapped to the raring series for the PPA, then the `~quantal1` version of the package will not exist. You'll have to swap that around for `~raring1` most likely.